# Does this double series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $p>1$ and $q>1$ be two positive integers.

Does this double series converges

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{mp+jq}}$$

Comment: Try breaking it into two series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. since $a_j=\big\{\frac{1}{2^{mp+jq}}\big\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is a geometric sequence $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{mp+jq}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2^{mp+q}}}{1-\frac{1}{2^q}}=\frac{2^{-mp}}{2^q-1}$$apply the sum the (similar) claim for the remaining sum and you get a nice geometric seies which converegs as usual to a number which depends on $p$ and $q$